# Postgres insists on Primary Key in Group By statement whereas SQLite does not

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am having a problem with Postgres insisting the primary key is part of the “group by” clause, the frustration being that the syntax I have works perfectly with SQLITE.

The error message is ‘column "attendees.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function’

My question is can anyone provide the fix such that Postgres will produce the output that SQLite does (SQL statement, schema, data and desired output provided below)

My table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Attendees
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
activitynumber int,
activitydate DATE,
club int,
usernum int,
username ,
activityname ,
cost int,
received int,
update_time DATETIME,
CONSTRAINT FK_activitynumber
  FOREIGN KEY (activitynumber)
  REFERENCES Activity(activitynumber)
CONSTRAINT FK_club
  FOREIGN KEY (club)
  REFERENCES "club"(clubnum)
CONSTRAINT FK_usernum
  FOREIGN KEY (usernum)
  REFERENCES "users"(usernum)
);

CREATE INDEX ix_attendees_group ON Attendees 
(club,activitydate,activitynumber);
```

(Please note, I added the index to try and solve the problem but it didn’t).

```
activities =  Attendees.query.filter_by(club=current_user.club).order_by(Attendees.activitdate.desc()).group_by(Attendees.activitydate,Attendees.activitynumber)
```

The data I have is:-

```
id  activitynumber  activitydate    club    usernum username    activityname    cost    received    update_time
1   3   15-10-19    1002    1002000001  susan   Monday Swim 200 0   58:43.8
2   3   15-10-19    1002    1002000002  triblokerich    Monday Swim 200 0   58:49.9
3   4   17-10-19    1002    1002000001  susan   Thursday Swim   200 0   59:04.5
4   4   17-10-19    1002    1002000015  craig   Thursday Swim   200 0   59:09.9
5   6   16-10-19    1002    1002000001  susan   Dunton  200 0   00:06.5
6   6   16-10-19    1002    1002000002  triblokerich    Dunton  200 0   00:17.6
7   3   16-10-19    1002    1002000001  susan   Monday Swim 300 0   58:28.1
8   3   16-10-19    1002    1002000002  triblokerich    Monday Swim 300 0   58:33.7
9   3   16-10-19    1002    1002000015  craig   Monday Swim 300 0   58:37.7
10  3   16-10-19    1002    1002000016  craig2  Monday Swim 300 0   01:41.8
11  3   19-10-19    1002    1002000001  susan   Monday Swim 300 0   07:56.4
12  3   19-10-19    1002    1002000002  triblokerich    Monday Swim 300 0   08:04.8
```

and the output I am trying to get (which works with SQLite) is:

```
Date       Activity
2019-10-19 Monday Swim
2019-10-17 Thursday Swim
2019-10-16 Monday Swim
2019-10-16 Dunton
2019-10-15 Monday Swim
```

Comment: You might want to tag the language and library you use to run the query since it's not SQL. In general it seems you should have some kind of selection definition after the group by since you can't get the actual rows out after grouping, only an aggregate. This is what PostgreSQL is correctly complaining about.

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen; the languate is Python SQL Alchemy and the underlying SQL Syntax is as follows:-

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen; In SQL:  SELECT attendees.id AS attendees_id, attendees.activitynumber AS attendees_activitynumber, attendees.activitydate AS attendees_activitydate, attendees.club AS attendees_club, attendees.usernum AS attendees_usernum, attendees.username AS attendees_username, attendees.activityname AS attendees_activityname, attendees.cost AS attendees_cost, attendees.received AS attendees_received, attendees.update_time AS attendees_update_time FROM attendees WHERE attendees.club = 1002 GROUP BY attendees.activitydate, attendees.activitynumber ORDER BY attendees.activitydate DESC;

Comment: Please add the offending query to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Sqlite is much more relaxed about things like that than other databases. See https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause

Answer (score 1):

If I understand SQL Alchemy's syntax correctly you're looking for something like this, hopefully I'm not far off (broken into lines to show better):

```
activities =  Attendees.query\
  .with_entities(Attendees.activitydate, Attendees.activityname)\
  .filter_by(club=current_user.club)\
  .order_by(Attendees.activitdate.desc())\
  .group_by(Attendees.activitydate,Attendees.activityname)
```

You always need to have the not-grouped-by columns in the result set as aggregates (min, max, sum, etc) because there's no way to show them otherwise. Which ID for example would be taken from the grouping of five rows? SQLite may be one of the inaccurate databases that just throws any of the rows back but PostgreSQL is very strict about the query and will never do this.

In this query it is defined that the result should contain only the columns that are in the `group_by`, since those are what you need. It also has the `activityname` as a grouped column rather than `activitynumber` since they need to match. This way there's no un-aggregated non-grouped columns in the result, only the grouped ones and the query should work fine.

Comment: As an aside, there's that one exception to "You always need to have the not-grouped-by columns in the result set as aggregate": grouping by the primary key, in which case the possible non-aggregates are functionally dependent. Arises easily in a one-to-many join calculating aggregates from the "many" side.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - Thanks for the clear explanation of the cause, the correct code (which has worked like a dream), showing me the .with_entities capabiltiy and the better lay out with broken lines.

Comment: Umm, I think you've mixed up a bit, this is Sami Kuhmonen's answer.